# Help Identifying Components

Tags: capacitor

I guess these are capacitors... but I'm not sure. What are they exactly and how do I read their stripes?

[image]

The above picture gives the impression that the background is white paper, but it looks far from white, which obscures the colors of the parts.  If the background is indeed white, then here is a fixed version.  One of these two should be edited out once we know which one is the correct representation.

[image]

Comment: Clean your camera lens.  The blooming around light areas is so bad that it's hard to identify the colors.  Try to think about reflections and background too when you ask others to look at your pictures.

Comment: @OlinLathrop He is improving though... His last question didn't even have a photo :-)

Comment: I'm ignoring your sarcasm... This is from a mobile phone camera in a dark room without flash light.

Comment: And it was not about actually getting the capacities, but about identifying the kind of components. Otherwise I would have sorted them

Comment: @Max: It's not sarcasm.  There is no excuse for dumping bad pictures on us.  Your lens probably is dirty, which is the most likely cause of the blooming.  If this was in a dark room, turn the lights on.  Or take it to where there is more light, or shine a desk light on it, or use the camera's flash.  Again, there is no excuse for blatantly crappy pictures, especially when you are using them to ask others for a favor.

Comment: Retaken, cropped, straightened and scaled. I hope this is enough to satisfy you. I won't comment on your understanding of favor...

Comment: @Max: Much better, but is that white paper there things are sitting on?  Also, its out of line to get snippy.  Yes, you are here asking for free help (the favor) from a large number of people.  That by itself is fine since that's the purpose of this site.  However, you are not owed anything here either.  People will respond and help only if they feel like it.  Dumping bad pictures is disrespecting everyone else here, just like bad writing text-speak and the like would be.  Those things don't help getting the desired response.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think you need to ease up a bit on the picture quality requirements. There is no reason the picture needs to have completely perfect whites. I can read all of the colors on the first image just fine. In fact, I find the first image much easier to look at since the colors are slightly softer.

Comment: Also, there is no reason we should ever be telling someone the specific values of all of those capacitors. This is not what the OP wanted at all. He wanted to know how to figure out the value, not have us give it to him. For this reason there really is no value in having perfect color. All we needed was the general idea of what the things looked like in order to confirm that they were capacitors, the very first image he posted was plenty good for this to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are film capacitors, typically ranging from a few nF up to a few uF. The colour code is similar to that for resistors, and read from the top.

Comment: Like this one? http://www.csgnetwork.com/capcccalc.html

Comment: Your DMM should be able to tell you the capacitance.

Comment: Not all DMMs have capacitance modes. In fact very few do until you get into some of the higher end DMMs.

Comment: [BK2709B](http://www.tequipment.net/BK2709B.html) <== I have this $100 DMM. I guess I shouldn't assume I have the baseline functionality in my equipment. :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to say that you can't get a DMM with capacitance measurement for cheap, rather I was just trying to say that it isn't typical. I would also bet many hobbyist would consider $100 for a DMM on the higher end of their price range.

Comment: It was highend, but it's around 20y old